# Remove an object from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I want to remove an object from a collection if the object does'nt satisfies some condition

```
      foreach (var data in infData)
          {
            if(data.Id==0)
             {
               //Remove this object from the collection
             }
          }
```

How to do this.

EDIT: This is the complete code

```
foreach (var data in infData)
        {
            //Validate Offence Code
            IQueryable<Ref_OffenceCode> allRows = dbContext.Ref_OffenceCode;
            if (allRows.Where(p => p.Code == data.offenceCode && p.StartDate<=data.offenceDate ).Count() == 0)
            {
                invalidCount += 1;
            }

            //Validate Location Code
            //IQueryable<Ref_OffenceCode> allRows = dbContext.Ref_OffenceCode;
            if (invalidCount != 0)
            {
                infData.Remove(data);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How you do it depends on what specific type of collection you're using.

Comment: If by "collection" you mean IEnumerable, you can't. What is the type of `infData` ?

Comment: That is not the complete code, it will not compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of removing the object from the collection you could create a new filtered collection:

```
var filteredList = infData.Where(x => x.Id != 0);
```

and leave the GC take care of the old collection when it falls out of scope. Also you mentioned ArrayList in your post. Unless you are using .NET 1.1 or older there's absolutely no reason to use `ArrayList`. A generic collection would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I am using a generic collection. Please see the complete code in edit section

Comment: You better call `ToList()` else you will still refer to the original collection and will see subsequent modification too, which is perhaps what you do not want.

Answer (score 3):

for `List` do this:

```
infData = infData.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == 0)
```

and in General you can do this (for enumerable):

```
enumerable = enumerable.Except(enumerable.Where(p => p.Id == 0));
```

Comment: This works for `List<T>`, but the OP doesn't say what specific type of collection they're using.

Comment: I like the .Except(). Don't get to use that often. +1

Comment: The `Except` version is pretty pointless as it stands. Why not just use `enumerable = enumerable.Where(p => p.Id != 0);` instead?

Comment: @LukeH, 2 reason: first I wrote my answer for List at first then when I want to update it I see @Darin use it, second the order is not difference but, the readability is good when you want to have a positive `if` statements, like @vaibhav situation, you should demorgan all statements to use Where( x != y || z != u) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `foreach` if you want to remove an item from a collection (since you are modifying the collection while iterating over it).

You can use an index based approach, but recall that the collection size will change. If you only need to remove *one* item, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infData.Count; i++)
{
  if(infData[i].Id==0)
  {
    infData.RemoveAt(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

As @Stefano comments, you can iterate backwards and then you don't need to break (and can remove multiple items):

```
for (int i = infData.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
  if(infData[i].Id==0)
  {
    infData.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: another option with this solution is to count down instead of up : for(int i = data.count; i>0 ; i--). But i prefer to build a new collection

Comment: shouldo what Stefano said and no break. ( but i = data.count -1 not count)

Comment: @Downvoter - care to explain? What is incorrect with my answer?

Comment: @Oded, I downvoted you 4 mins ago and you correct your answer now and it's steal false, you should do `infData.Count - 1` not `infData.Count`

Comment: @Oded, your answer is steel false.